# Why does square brackets appear in Pandas DataFrame only when I append to list?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a loop that extracts some info from several files, each containing a list of actions taken in a game. If I run the following code, I get a dataframe with the correct output (the GameId without brackets).

```
GameId = ['23456']
dfWant = pd.DataFrame({'GameId': GameId})
print(dfWant)
```

But If I loop through the files and try to add each item to a list, the resulting dataframe contains square brackets. Why does this output differ? And how can I make the code below output the GameId without square brackets in the DataFrame?

```
GameId = ['12345']
GameIdList = []
GameIdList.append(Game)
dfHave = pd.DataFrame({'GameId': GameIdList})
print(dfHave)
```

Comment: Because `append` adds the list as an element to the other list, creating a nested list. Try `GameIdList.extend(Game)` instead

Comment: Change `GameIdList.append(Game)` to `GameIdList.extend(Game)` to retain a flat list.

Comment: That certainly works in the example code, however, in my programming loop, I get the following error: ValueError: arrays must all be same length

Comment: Nevermind, works when I do this:a = {'GameId': GameId,
     'Player': Player,
     'Placement': Placement}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a, orient='index')
df = df.transpose()

Answer (score 0):

This works great on python 3.7 :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The follwing solved my problem.

```
GameId = ['12345']
GameIdList = []
GameIdList.extend(Game)
a = {'GameId': GameIdList}
dfHave = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a, orient = 'index')
dfHave = dfHave.transpose()
```